# BadImageFormatException when running application

Tags: c#, vb.net, badimageformatexception

I get a *BadImageFormatException* when running a C#/VB SmartClient application with the `Any CPU` configuration. If I use `x86` configuration then it runs fine. This is an old, legacy project which I occasionally have to modify and I don't know the history, so  I can only guess that there are dlls that contain 32-bit native code causing this error. This all makes sense, except that when the configuration is `Debug` & `AnyCPU` it runs, only when the configuration is `Release` & `AnyCPU` does it fail. I see no significant differences in the Debug.cfg.xml and Release.cfg.xml files.

Can anyone say why it would run in the `Debug` configuration? Since this works I wonder if it is somehow possible to get it running in x64 (ie AnyCPU)

From the app.config:

```
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
```

Comment: It is pretty common for "old" .NET apps to be built with AnyCPU but never actually tested on a 64-bit operating system.  And have a dependency on 32-bit native code.  So sure, changing the target to x86 is the proper thing to do.  Not the solution's Platform name, it is irrelevant, the only setting that matters is the one for the EXE project, Project + Properties, Build tab.

Comment: Are you running in debug mode via the IDE or are you building with debug mode and launching the app directly?

Comment: Debug mode in the IDE (Visual Studio 2010)

Answer (score 1):

Your application almost certainly depends on a 32 bit component. When you run your application as a 64 bit process, it fails to load that 32 bit component into your process.

Possible solutions include:

1. Revert to running as 32 bit.
2. Find a 64 bit version of the dependent component.

Comment: Yes, it currently builds with 32 bit. The question of how it builds in Debug but not in Release is still unresolved.

Comment: Builds? This is a runtime error. Can you be clear what the problem is please. You now seem to be contradicting yourself.

Comment: Sorry, `runs`, not `builds`. My mistake.

Comment: Well, you do need to work out why you sometimes run as 32 bit, and sometimes as 64 bit.

Comment: It *never* runs as 64 bit, always as 32 bit.

Comment: The error message suggests otherwise. How did you verify that you are not running 64 bit?

Comment: By setting the configuration to x86

Comment: Not according to the question. You are running AnyCPU.

Comment: When setting it to x86, it runs. When setting it to x64 or AnyCPU, I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing window or form icon image format from .jpg to .png. sometimes on windows server this  error occurred because of icon image format.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't know this. As it happens, all image files are already .png.

Comment: I must say that I find this hard to believe.

Comment: But I must say that I am happy the way my issue was solved once.

Comment: I am sorry for bad describing my mean.

Comment: It's true that app icons cannot be jpeg, but I don't think the loader will reject such an executable with that exception.

Comment: I see this exception only in windows server 2008 and after this exception application will be closed.